# Getting Day Name in an Object Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get the current day name in an object which I can then use to perform a basic calculation. Going around in circles currently.

I've got some attributes like this:

```
 @location.monday_on
 @location.monday_off
 @location.tuesday_on
 .....
```

I'm using these to figure out whether Time.now is within the range:

```
(@location.monday_on.to_i..@location.monday_off.to_i).include? Time.now.hour
```

That works fine. However, I wanted to dry things up and tried this:

```
start = "@location.#{Time.now.strftime('%A').downcase}_on".constantize
finish = "@location.#{Time.now.strftime('%A').downcase}_off".constantize

(start.to_i..finish.to_i).include? Time.now.hour
```

But, that gives an error about the wrong constant name. Was clutching at straws.

What's the best way to get the name of the current day in the object so I can use in a lookup?

Comment: Are you just trying to find whether today is a certain day or are `monday_on` and `monday_off` more complex than that?  Could you get away with using [`Time#monday?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-wday) and friends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly:

```
@location.send("#{Time.now.strftime('%A').downcase}_on".to_sym)
```

However, at the *very* least, that functionality should be wrapped up in whatever class `@location` is, otherwise the mainline code is cluttered with irrelevant code.

I might have encapsulated the results of those functions in a hash or array, and pass in either a day name or DoW number. Creating day-specific methods is nice if they're being used in a DSL or other user-facing artifact, otherwise I'm not convinced of their utility.

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know you could do that. I agree with your comment too about day-specific methods. I dislike having 14 attributes for a basic time of day scheduler. Am using the fields in a jquery range slider - do you think it would be better to use a hash instead?

Comment: @simonmorley Either a hash or an array would be preferable, indexed by the DoW number. I'd probably keep the values as times rather than a bare integer hour. An array or hash could be stored as a serialized field--or you could use an AR relation. I don't know enough about jQuery's range slider to know what the "best" option is.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help @dave-newton. Not familiar with jquery either, just trying to learn it - am fitting in an existing application around someone else's javascript which poses problems. Will experiment with your suggestions. Cheers, Simon.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you *can* use metaprogramming doesn't mean you *should*.  Metaprogramming is fun and in some situations helps you write more readable code, but, as your example shows, it can lead to horrid looking data-driven code.  Honestly I cannot even be sure I understand what you are trying to do from looking at your code.

In general, though, Date arithmetic is very hard due to all the special cases.  Even Ruby doesn't fully support it because it is so hard.  But even with Ruby's ignorance of "summer time" you are better off using `Date` and `DateTime` as a basis rather than trying to roll your own.

In general, you should not be trying to use day names in calculations.  Instead, use day numbers (i.e. weekday is 0..6) and only convert to strings when necessary using something like `Date::DAYNAMES[weekday]`. Then you can use something like `@location.wday == DateTime.now.wday`

Comment: Point taken about using numbers over names. Learning as I go. S

Comment: I'd argue that this code is intrinsically data-driven by definition since it relies on data to make a decision and that the issue is input values are encapsulated in method names. The intent is clear--is the current hour contained in today's time-on/time-off range. I'm ambivalent about day names v. DoW numbers in general since it's a one-to-one conversion.

Comment: (I don't fully grok the downvote, though; this is essentially the same answer as mine, just longer and w/o the solution that shouldn't be used.)

Comment: @DaveNewton, I never said your solution wasn't data-driven and of course your way works. I said (or meant to say) that plugging data into method names leads to horrid looking code.  I would argue that the intent of `@location.send("#{Time.now.strftime('%A').downcase}_on".to_sym)` is not nearly as clear as `@location.wday(wday).include? Time.now`. The standard paradigm of passing data as arguments to functions rather than as the name of the function is standard for a reason. Furthermore, using numbers for weekdays makes it easier to perform calculations and interface with JavaScript.

Comment: @OldPro I don't think anybody is arguing the resulting code is particularly readable, although the snippets in the comment aren't equivalent, nor do I think anybody implied embedding data values in method names was a good idea-I think the general consensus was that it wasn't. Whether or not it's "easier to perform calculations and interface with JavaScript" depends on what you're actually doing, and again, since it's one-to-one, it barely matters.

Comment: @DaveNewton, it seems to me that by proposing the answer that you did and by the OP accepting it as the best answer you both were implying that embedding data values in method names is a good idea.  I'm taking a stand that it is not a good idea.  I would have provided a fuller solution if I completely understood what the OP was trying to accomplish in sufficient detail.

Comment: I answered the question, then said it wasn't a great idea. Just because simmering isn't a great shortish doesn't mean that the original approach should be blithely ignored or that the technique is *never* of any value. You can make up whatever interpretation you want, I guess, although since I explicitly stated both in the answer and in the comments that a DoW number would be cleaner, I find it a odd-but that's just me.